# Return 410 (Gone) for URLs containing hash symbol

Tags: googlebot, http-status-code-410

A previous development of a flash based site used URLs of the form http://www.example.com/#!
These URLs have been indexed by Google but I need these URLs to be removed from the search index. Reading the Google documentation, I should be generating a 404 or 410 error.

However, I can't do it on the server-side because the # and everything after it is not included in the GET request. Therefore, in my .htaccess file, there is no way to check for URLs of this form.

I can detect those URLs with the Javascript line below

window.location.hash.match('#!')

then change window.location to a URL that my .htaccess file can match and then use a RewriteRule to return a 410 error.

But will this work with the search bots and/or is there a better way?

Thanks.